# How to copy and paste Windows' warnings?

Tags: windows, windows-10, copy-paste, notifications

Say I do something and Windows gives me warning; something like this:

[image]

Now I want to capture the text:

> Sorry, this PC doesn't meet the hardware
>   requirements for recording clips. Learn more.

So I can search that in Google.

Well I can't. The only way I can do so is to type some and search in Google and someone else have the complete quote.

How can I copy the text from popup messages like this, to the clipboard?

Let me try something else.

I try to open excel. write some garbage, and then quit. A notification will ask if I want to save changes.

[image]

That want to save your changes to book1 is also not selectable and clickable.

In fact, I do not know any notification in windows that's selectable and clickable.

Am I missing something?

Comment: They just type it in.

Comment: any idea why microsoft makes it difficult for anyone to just copy and paste this?

Comment: Only Microsoft knows why Microsoft does anything. :)

Comment: click in the message and press **CRTL** + **C**

Comment: Take a screen shot and later type yourself.... Or use OCR

Comment: @magicandre1981 that is the plan. Obviously I can't do that and hence the question. I can't do that for MOST notification

Comment: Modern apps are crazy, really. Perhaps you can submit a feedback to Microsoft using the Feedback app, and some of us here may upvote it.

Comment: normal messageboxes can be copied with CTRL+C. If this doesn't work, I have no idea

Comment: you can't even select the text

Comment: is this a new toast notification?

Comment: what is toast notification? there are many other notifications I can't select

Comment: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-copy-text-or-error-messages-from-any-dialog-boxes-in-windows/  maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Inspect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx) tool that comes with the [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk). When the installer asks you which features you want, only choose the Windows Software Development Kit; the other stuff isn't relevant. Once the installation is complete, you'll find `inspect.exe` here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64
```

(Drop the `(x86)` and change `x64` to `x86` if your machine is 32-bit.)

When Inspect opens, make sure only Watch Cursor is enabled, like this:

[image: watch cursor]

Now move your mouse so that the element you want to get text out of is under the cursor. Wait for Inspect to update the main pane with that element's information. Then quickly move your mouse back over the Inspect window and click the appropriate toolbar button to disable Watch Cursor. You can then browse the object's properties and copy text out as you would expect.

[image: selecting the text]

Note that it's really easy to deadlock Inspect - sometimes just closing any window will do it. Running as administrator seems to help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. The easiest way I know is to take a screenshot, send it to your phone and open it with Google Goggles, which has text recognition:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.unveil

You might also be able to just take a screenshot, save it somewhere and then drag it in the search bar of Google Photo Search. Sometimes it works, sometimes not.